# Is this Loquat?

Tags: identification

This is coming up in a pot of unknown seeds. Loquats are one of the many seeds in the group of old seeds planted. If it is a loquat, it is the second generation grown from seed. Thank you.[image: Loquat?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They look just like the leaves on my 40 ft. loquat tree. The fruit is just starting to turn yellow ( zone 8).